# Update regression tree with new data

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I have a dataset with 2500 instances. There's an attribute in the dataset which I'd like to create different linear regression models based on its value (therefore I'm using regression tree)

I wonder how I can update the model, when new instances (~100 instances) loads in to the dataset every hour. I prefer not to create the model from  scratch everytime.

(I'm planning to use Weka library, but I'm open to any other java machine learning library that can help me in this sense)

Comment: I'm sure you can do it in python sklearn. Check http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html for "Incremental learning"

Comment: @Stergios I'm doing it in Java.

Answer (score 0):

in general, as you may have suggested the default approach is to start from scratch again. Nevertheless, there is a quite straight forward way to improve the tree by the time without rebuilding it too often.

For your n data records, I would suggest the following approach:

- Look if the error in one leaf node is bigger than you can tolerate for these samples
- Look if for this specific leaf node you have more than m (boundary you need to choose) sample that are beyond your tolerance boundary
- Pic them and build a new very small tree at the end of this leaf node

If you use sklearn there are methods like *dtree.decision_path* and *dtree.apply* that can be helpful here. See for more details

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor

I would guess that in your case a very small tree added at the end of the primary tree for “refinement” should be enough. I am more familiar with sklearn and MATLAB but I assume Weak provide similar methods.

Good speed

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use R or tensorflow where you get to save your models and reload them, if thats what you are asking.
As far as I understand, you want to improve your model for every new set of 100 instances, right ??
If that is the case then R, tensorflow or sklearn should help and would suggest you to try python for machine learning.